# Bundler: "Failed to build gem native extensions", "Cannot allocate memory"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I'm trying to get Rails working on Ubuntu for Windows(beta).  I installed RVM, updated my ruby to 2.3.0, and installed Rails without any problem.  When I try to generate a new Rails project, it goes well until Bundler runs.  I am getting an identical error for many of my Gems. Here is a specific instance:

```
Installing byebug 9.0.5 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/djllap/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/byebug-9.0.5/ext/byebug
/home/djllap/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160801-16013-15q7ntv.rb extconf.rb
Cannot allocate memory - /home/djllap/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160801-16013-15q7ntv.rb extconf.rb 2>&1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/djllap/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/byebug-9.0.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/djllap/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/byebug-9.0.5/gem_make.out
```

I haven't had this problem running Rails on Windows or my Vagrant/Virtual Box VMs.  I would love to get this working on Ubuntu for Windows though, so I don't need to worry about all of that VM stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your server is running out of memory. Either increase the amount of RAM, or add some swap space to help alleviate the problem.

Digital Ocean has a [great tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04) on how to add swap space to a Ubuntu machine.

Comment: I tried running Bundler again while keeping an eye on my RAM usage, and I didn't even see a spike, let alone one that exceeded my capacity.  According to Task Manager I had about 2 gigs of free RAM throughout the entire process.

Comment: Furthermore, I am able to run Bundler without errors in a VM that uses another 1GB of RAM.

Comment: Okay yea that's not the problem then, 2GB is plenty. Even 512MB usually suffices. I've just noticed you're using Ubuntu for Windows.. I'm not sure what the issue is to be honest but it doesn't sound like it's stable enough for this yet.

Comment: Did a bit more research; see my other answer. My mistake for missing that initially!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think you might be out of luck with Ubuntu for Windows. The way it actually works is by translating the Linux commands into Windows, and Microsoft have only implemented some of those commands. Byebug (and many other gems) utilise native C extensions and it looks like some of these are failing.

Take a look at [this article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3094422/windows/ubuntus-unity-desktop-shows-the-limits-of-windows-10s-bash-shell.html) for more info. You might get the support you want one day, but since Microsoft don't want to focus on server technology, instead encouraging VMs, I would probably save myself the pain. Gem installs are flakey enough in native bash..

Answer (score 0):

Add swap or increase you swap partition. Seems compiler using swap when compiling.
I have checked free mem state found there is free mem, but my ECS have no /swap, so I configured host swap on, then everything goes well. Hopes it can help.